EventListener for localstorage not working from react code
i got one token from login api which i have set to the localstorage and in app.js file i have one condition like below code
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./Component/Home";
import Login from "./Component/Login";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  const [token, setToken]= useState(!!localStorage.getItem('token'));
  
  const handleStorageChange = () => {
      const newToken = !!localStorage.getItem('token');
      setToken(newToken);
    };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {token ?(
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        ) : (
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        )}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;


We need to redirect to the home component when the token value is present in the localStorage.
this is how i'm login the user
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("AUTH_API", {
        username : username,
        password : pass,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        localStorage.setItem("token",res.data.token);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        toast("Please Enter Valid Details!");
      });
  };


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event: "The storage event of the Window interface fires when a storage area (localStorage or sessionStorage) has been modified in the context of another document." - unless I am mistaken about how React fundamentally works, you don't have different documents here, but only a single one.

Using localStorage for storing auth data is something more than horrible :-!

@CBroe yes that is correct but that localstorage events is working when i change from the localstorage but from reactjs it is not triggering.

You might not need to add storage listner, simply call handleStorageChange in useEffect -- mounting.. u can skip removing on unmounting

@Amirhosein do you have any other idea for do this ?

You can make simple by using useNavigate() hook to redirect to the after the successful response from the api store the token in the localStorage and redirect to the Home page using useNavigate. You should use app.js to configure routers only. not to place any condition to make that simple.
You can take reference from here

That's right but i not have to route name please see my app.js file
